# On Firebase, I make sure that user can not delete their Auth information?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

In my app I use phone number auth, because it is important to ban abusive users. But how can I make sure that someone would not just simply delete their Auth data and sign up again with same phone number and receive a new profile and UID?

Comment: Instead of doing this with authentication you could consider doing this in your database with security rules. Make sure a user can't delete/change their data and block access when they are banned.

Comment: I will do that, but if there was a way to ensure users can not delete their Auth data, things would be much simpler.

Comment: Isn't this a problem in many systems? Most applications allow users to unsubscribe/delete their account (users should be able to do that). Any user can delete their account from some application and sign up again. If you are worried about abuse, you could also key things based on some more permanent identifier like email or phoneNumber.

Comment: yeah, i'll do that